# How to architect nested Fragments in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, design-patterns, android-architecture-navigation

I have a ViewPager, which holds 3 Fragments. One of the fragments is a ScrollView, with several distinct sections (an About Me screen with photo uploading, details, settings sections).

I'm decoupling business logic with using MVVM, but still the Fragment is quite large (700 lines of code), as all of the sections need a great deal of UI logic (RecyclerViews, reactive fields, onActivityResult-related stuff).

If the Fragment was an Activity instead, I could just add all 3 sections as separate Fragments and manage communication with the Activity, but since it's a Fragment I'm not sure how to organise these nested sections so that they are not in one class but can still communicate with each other.

Comment: Fragments support nesting Fragments within them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can do nested fragments. I suggest split up your logic in multiple fragments to make it more modular and reusable.

This is the approach i would follow:

- you have viewPager with 3 fragments. I suppose first fragment has too
  much in it and this is what you want to split using nested fragments.
- define layouts using multiple frameLayouts. In each framelayout, you
  can insert a fragment.
- so something like: (this is not a real code but rather something to
  describe the potential solution)

Comment: Perfect. I was thinking about using a vertical ViewPager for some reason, but I see that ChildFragmentManager is very powerful and behaves just like a normal FragmentManager.